# Chuwi Hi10 Dualboot Randomly Powers Off after 60%ish??? Only in Windows/ Linux not in Android

Tags: windows-10, power, tablet

I've had my Chuwi Hi10 for well over a year now and for a couple of months, I've had this annoying issue where the tablet powers off randomly without any warning or message. It does not occur when I am charging the device!

It occured first in Windows 10 and it wasn't before long that I realized the issue didn't occur in Android.

My next step was to install Linux in order to see if this was a driver issue? It wasn't, because by the time the install had finished I was at about 50% and the tablet would shut down almost instantleously after boot up.

One thing I did realize was that the issue didn't really occur in Windows Server 2016 (I have a student license from Microsoft Imagine). It only occured once and that may have been from overheating?

Yes, it's a very weird issue. It might be to do with voltage within the BIOS considering that dualboot support comes out of the box and perhaps I could solve it with a setting. Or it may be to do with the battery.
Any help would be appreciated.

*System Specs: Chuwi Hi10 Intel Atom x5-Z8300 4gb ram 64gb SSD Integrated Graphics*

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your battery not reporting accurate information.

Comment: The battery seems to have the correct percentage in the taskbar @Ramhound

Comment: I am saying your battery is reporting inaccurate information if, your device turns off, with 60% of the battery remaining.  "It does not occur when I am charging the device!" - The fact this happens supports my conclusion.  "It only occurred once and that may have been from overheating?" - It is very unlikely your device is overheating.

Comment: But surely if Windows reports that there is 60% of battery, the OS won't shut the tablet down right? @Ramhound

Comment: I am saying the battery indicator is reporting 60% but the battery must be discharged a great deal more then only 40%.  The `x5-Z8300` came out in 2015, given the price tag of this particular device, I wouldn't have expected the battery to last as long as it did honestly.

Comment: But then wb Android? The device manages to run perfectly fine in Android @Ramhound

Comment: Can’t help with Android.